# Apply Hough Transform to only certain section of an image - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have created bounding boxes for a set of words as mentioned here using MATLAB

[Draw bounding boxes for entire word instead of each character in an image - MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698456/draw-bounding-boxes-for-entire-word-instead-of-each-character-in-an-image-matl)

Now, I would like to copy the contents of the region specified by each bounding box into another matrix for further computation.

How can I do that given the coordinates of the bounding box?

---

EDIT

Discovered a problem while using the method mentioned by @beaker

This is the original code where `binary` is the image file in binary format.

`Ibox(:,cnt)` gives me the coordinates of each rectangle drawn.

```
imshow(normal);
boxes = zeros(0,1);
Sp = 10.5;
binclosed = imclose(binary, strel('rectangle',[4 ceil(Sp/2)]));
[Ilabel,num] = bwlabel(binclosed);
Iprops = regionprops(Ilabel, 'BoundingBox');
Ibox = reshape([Iprops.BoundingBox],[4 num]);
for cnt=1:num
    rectangle('position',Ibox(:,cnt),'edgecolor','r');
    X = (Ibox(:,cnt))';
    X1 = X(1);
    Y1 = X(2);
    W = X(3);
    H = X(4);
    X2 = X1 + W;
    Y2 = Y1 - H;
    coords = [X1,Y1,X2,Y2];
    boxes = [boxes;coords];
end
```

Now `boxes` is storing each regions coordinates.
To extract the region, I was doing

```
for c=1:num
    subimage = binary(boxes(c,1:2),boxes(c,3:4));
    imshow(subimage);
end
```

which gave me random clippings of the original image.

When I checked the value of coordinates in `boxes` I found that they were in float.

How is that happening if my image is in binary format?

Comment: See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html

Comment: @beaker I did exactly that.
I am using the coordinates I used to plot my rectangle to get the start and end points for each region. Now, when I am using those points to copy the data for each region into another matrix, I find that those coordinates are in float. How is that possible if my image is in binary form?

Comment: Your original question says nothing about changing from binary to float being the problem. How are we supposed to know how to answer your question if you don't give us enough information to know what the actual problem is? Please post a [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code sample that demonstrates your problem, along with the at least the dimensions and types of the input and output matrices, both actual and desired.

Comment: @beaker That wasn't the original problem.
This was a discovered problem. I tried your initial solution, it worked but not quite as expected.
I shall upload the necessary information and update my query.

Comment: @beaker Please check now. I have updated the problem.

Comment: The coordinates of the bounding box are not integer because the boundary of the enclosing rectangle falls between two pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relatively K.I.S.S. solution.

`boxes = boxes - 0.5;` fixed the floating point problem.

The rest of the code is as follows:

```
for c=1:num
    ir=1;
    for xcoord = boxes(c,1):boxes(c,2)
        ic=1;
        for ycoord = boxes(c,3):boxes(c,4)
            z(ir,ic) = binary(ycoord, xcoord);
            ic=ic+1;
        end
        ir=ir+1;
    end
    if(size(z) < 100)
        break;
    else
        str = sprintf(saveFile,c);
        imwrite(z, [folder '\cropped\' str],'jpg');
    end
    clear z;
end
```

Here I am just saving the cropped images to a folder for later use using `imwrite`.